# R - How to mutate a function in loop to count given words and add a new column for each

Tags: r, loops, apply, dplyr

I have a data frame that shows messages received from various users (one user per row). I have written a function (called CountSelectWords) that can count the instances of a given word or phrase in each message.

Now I am trying to write a script that will run the counting function on the data frame with a lexicon of words I've concatenated.

I have successfully been able to use mutate to add new columns with the count for one word at a time, but how can I create a loop to run this on multiple words?

I tried using a for loop, as well as apply, but to no avail.

Here is the code that works to add individual columns:

```
data_frame2 <- data_frame1 %>% 
  mutate(word1 = CountSelectWords(chat_description, "word1"), 
         word2 = CountSelectWords(chat_description, "word2"))
```

where "word1" and "word2" are the words to search in each message; and "chat_description" is the column name of interest.

The result is a new data frame (data_frame2) with 2 additional columns titled "word1" and "word2" respectively, which list the count of those words in each row.

However, when I try to write a lexicon of words and create a for loop based on this, it doesn't work:

```
lexicon <- c("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5")

for (i in lexicon) {

  data_frame3 <- data_frame1 %>% 
    mutate(paste("countof", as.character(i), sep = "_") = CountSelectWords(chat_description, i))
}
```

I get the following error message when I attempt to run the for loop:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"data_frame3 <- data_frame1 %>% 
    mutate(paste("countof", as.character(i), sep = "_") ="
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
wordvec <- c("word1", "word2")
map_dfc(wordvec ~ CountSelectWords(chat_description, .x)) %>%
        rename_all(~ str_c("countof_", wordvec)) %>%     
        bind_cols(data_frame1, .)
```

---

In the `for` loop, if we wanted to assign use `:=`

```
data_frame3 <- data_frame1
for (i in lexicon) {

  data_frame3 <- data_frame3 %>% 
    mutate( !! paste("countof", i, sep = "_") := 
            CountSelectWords(chat_description, i))
}
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
set.seed(24)
iris$chat_description <- sample(c("word1", "word2"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)
lexicon <- wordvec
for(i in lexicon) {
     iris <- iris %>%
                mutate(!! paste("countof", i, sep="_") := 
                      sum(chat_description == i))

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried your for loop method and got the following error:
`Error in stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)` 
And the map option produces this error: `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default` 
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @GiselleSleapy  Can you check your function `CountSelectWords` as the incorrect nested parentheses is not happening in the code I showed